# postfix relayhost 'Recipient is not recognized. Relay access denied'

Tags: postfix, smtp, sasl

I'm trying to get  postfix to send emails through my smtp account with another email provider (in this case lavabit.com)

I'm getting the error

> Recipient is not recognized. Relay access denied

which makes me think its trying to send the email to that external smtp and its rejecting it because there is no account there of that address, rather than authenticating with my account logins and sending the email through the external smtp as that account (me).

My sasl_passwd file reads:

```
mail.lavabit.com    user@lavabit.com:password
```

and my master.cf reads:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = vps.httech.com.au
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = vps.httech.com.au, localhost.httech.com.au, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
allow_percent_hack = no
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_maps
debug_peer_list = lavabit.com
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
relayhost = mail.lavabit.com
```

Also at moment `relayhost_maps` is empty, though eventually I want to use it, to only forward one address's emails not them all.

Comment: funny coincidence.. i used lava bit too for ages since when they where nerdshack... :) sad what happened to him...

Answer (score 1):

ok, the reason it was in fact not authenticating was i needed  :

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

not just:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

as smtp_sasl_auth_enable is for the smtp client part of postfix (postfix sending emails)

and smtp_sasl_auth_enable is for the smpt server part of postfix (postfix recieving emails)